# Generated Allure Report is blank through Maven

Tags: java, maven, java-11, rest-assured, allure

I have a RestAssured framework which I wanted to add Allure test reporting as a POC, unfortunately the Allure report seems to be blank. I've Googled around and tried a few solutions including some on here but none worked for me.

I feel I am overlooking something simple (I hope), could anyone help me. Also my pom is below.

`pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>restAssuredAllure</groupId>
    <artifactId>restAssuredAllure</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://artifactory.euw.platformservices.io/artifactory/maven-central/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>UK Central</name>
            <url>https://artifactory.euw.platformservices.io/artifactory/maven-central/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven_central</id>
            <name>Maven Central</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.class</include>
                    </includes>
                                        <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.19/aspectjweaver-1.9.19.jar"
                    </argLine>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <allure.results.directory>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</allure.results.directory>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.19</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportVersion>2.21.0</reportVersion>
                    <resultsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</resultsDirectory>
                    <reportDirectory>${project.build.directory}/allure-report</reportDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.cdimascio</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-dotenv</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.32</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I've also tried generating the report with Allure2 and it's the same, blank report. I am outputting my results to `/target/allure-results` looking at time stamps on my files.

I've tried different versions of the dependencies, plugins and output report but it's still the same. Only way I've got the report populated is using the Junit 5 dependency and pointing to the `/target/surefire-reports` but they don't look quite as good as what I have seen for Rest Assured

running `mvn clean test` and then `mvn allure:report` and `mvn allure:serve` as per Allure docs.

I have tried the below for RestAssured as per docs aswell.

```
RestAssured
    .given(requestSpecification)
    .filter(new AllureRestAssured())
```

or

```
new RequestSpecBuilder().addFilter(new AllureRestAssured())
```

Tried to view report in Chrome and Safari.

I've have tried setting java agent and dependency in maven surefire plugin:
`-javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.19/aspectjweaver-1.9.19.jar"`

[image: generated report]

Comment: Just two hints. JUnit 5.9.x has significant changes to 5.8 and some frameworks not fully supported yet. I suggest downrade JUnit to 5.8. Finaly, please follow this instructions https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_junit_5  There are some extra settings which are missing in your snippet around surefire plugin configuration

Comment: I've made some changes , downgraded to JUnit 5.8 and followed the Allure docs for Junit5. It's worked. 
Didn;t think I needed JUnit 5 as it would use Rest Assured for some reason. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: have u tried allure generate command that will generate allure-report folder?